# Help speeding up a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

basically i want to perform diagonal averaging in R. Below is some code adapted from the simsalabim package to do the diagonal averaging. Only this is slow.

Any suggestions for vectorizing this instead of using sapply?

```
reconSSA <- function(S,v,group=1){
### S : matrix
### v : vector

    N <- length(v)
    L <- nrow(S)
    K <- N-L+1
    XX <- matrix(0,nrow=L,ncol=K)
    IND <- row(XX)+col(XX)-1
    XX <- matrix(v[row(XX)+col(XX)-1],nrow=L,ncol=K)
    XX <- S[,group] %*% t(t(XX) %*% S[,group])

    ##Diagonal Averaging
    .intFun <- function(i,x,ind) mean(x[ind==i])

    RC <- sapply(1:N,.intFun,x=XX,ind=IND)
    return(RC)
}
```

For data you could use the following

```
data(AirPassengers)
v <- AirPassengers
L <- 30
T <- length(v)
K <- T-L+1

x.b <- matrix(nrow=L,ncol=K)
x.b <- matrix(v[row(x.b)+col(x.b)-1],nrow=L,ncol=K)
S <- eigen(x.b %*% t(x.b))[["vectors"]] 
out <- reconSSA(S, v, 1:10)
```

Comment: Example data please.

Comment: i added some data. thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Excellent; you'll get much better answers with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can speed up the computation by almost 10 times with the help of a very specialized trick  with `rowsum`:

```
reconSSA_1 <- function(S,v,group=1){
### S : matrix
### v : vector
    N <- length(v)
    L <- nrow(S)
    K <- N-L+1
    XX <- matrix(0,nrow=L,ncol=K)
    IND <- row(XX)+col(XX)-1
    XX <- matrix(v[row(XX)+col(XX)-1],nrow=L,ncol=K)
    XX <- S[,group] %*% t(t(XX) %*% S[,group])
    ##Diagonal Averaging
    SUMS <- rowsum.default(c(XX), c(IND))
    counts <- if(L <= K) c(1:L, rep(L, K-L-1), L:1)
    else c(1:K, rep(K, L-K-1), K:1)
    c(SUMS/counts)
}

all.equal(reconSSA(S, v, 1:10), reconSSA_1(S, v, 1:10))
[1] TRUE

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(SSA = reconSSA(S, v, 1:10),
          SSA_1 = reconSSA_1(S, v, 1:10),
          columns = c( "test", "elapsed", "relative"),
          order = "relative")


    test elapsed relative
2 SSA_1    0.23   1.0000
1   SSA    2.08   9.0435
```

[Update: As Joshua suggested it could be speed up even further by using the crux of the rowsum code:

```
reconSSA_2 <- function(S,v,group=1){
### S : matrix
### v : vector
    N <- length(v)
    L <- nrow(S)
    K <- N-L+1
    XX <- matrix(0,nrow=L,ncol=K)
    IND <- c(row(XX)+col(XX)-1L)
    XX <- matrix(v[row(XX)+col(XX)-1],nrow=L,ncol=K)
    XX <- c(S[,group] %*% t(t(XX) %*% S[,group]))
    ##Diagonal Averaging
    SUMS <- .Call("Rrowsum_matrix", XX, 1L, IND, 1:N, 
                  TRUE, PACKAGE = "base")
    counts <- if(L <= K) c(1:L, rep(L, K-L-1), L:1)
    else c(1:K, rep(K, L-K-1), K:1)
    c(SUMS/counts)
}

   test elapsed  relative
3 SSA_2   0.156  1.000000
2 SSA_1   0.559  3.583333
1   SSA   5.389 34.544872
```

A speedup of ***x34.5*** comparing to original code!!

]

Comment: Very nice vectorization with `rowsums`!

Comment: You could make it even faster by only using the parts of `rowsums` that you need: (i.e. the `sort(unique(...))` and the `.Call("Rrowsum_matrix", ...)`.

Comment: :) rowsum was written for speed, I wish there were more funcs like this, specialized for grouped operations on arrays.

Comment: @Joshua  I remember experimenting with that, a half a year or so ago. It indeed speeds the stuff another 4 times, as far as I could remember. But one small error in inputs and your R session is gone:). Reorder might not be necessary for this example. So it might be quite worth rewriting the rowsum a bit.

Comment: It turned out that for this particular problem, unique was not necessary and the use of integer groups speed up the whole computation quite considerably.

Comment: Why is the scaling so different between the 3 different versions? they all have the right shape. the first version preserves the scale though...

Comment: @pslice, Sorry mate, I don't get what you mean by "scaling". All functions return a vector of diagonal means. So they are identical in that respect.

Comment: @VitoshKa : sorry about that. appears to be an error in my old code. burning too much midnight oil lately...

Comment: what if we want groups to be a list? Like groups= as.list(c(1:100))? Right now it won't accept this. I want it to reconstruct all 100 components separately or some form of a list. Any ideas?

Comment: @pslice, if you really need the group to be a list, do group <- unlist(group,F,F) inside the function.

Comment: Doesn't that just return them back as a vector? I'm talking about reconstructing say components 1-5 together and 6-10 together ,etc.. the output should be 2 vectors in this ex. not 1.

Comment: I just used something like this                    rc<-function(S,v,g) reconSSA_2(S,v,g)
groups=1:10
sapply(groups , rc, S=matrix, v=vector)

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your example to produce sensible results.  I think there are several errors in your function.

1. `XX` is used in `sapply`, but is not defined in the function
2. `sapply` works over `1:N`, where `N=144` in your example, but `x.b` only has 115 columns
3. `reconSSA` simply returns `x`

Regardless, I think you want:

```
data(AirPassengers)
x <- AirPassengers
rowMeans(embed(x,30))
```

---

UPDATE: I've re-worked and profiled the function.  Most of the time is spent in `mean`, so it may be hard to get this much faster using R code.  That said, you can 20% speedup by using `sum` instead.

```
reconSSA <- function(S,v,group=1){

    N <- length(v)
    L <- nrow(S)
    K <- N-L+1
    XX <- matrix(0,nrow=L,ncol=K)
    IND <- row(XX)+col(XX)-1
    XX <- matrix(v[row(XX)+col(XX)-1],nrow=L,ncol=K)
    XX <- S[,group] %*% t(t(XX) %*% S[,group])

    ##Diagonal Averaging
    .intFun <- function(i,x,ind) {
        I <- ind==i
        sum(x[I])/sum(I)
    }

    RC <- sapply(1:N,.intFun,x=XX,ind=IND)
    return(RC)
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I am looking for. The idea is to use the structure of x.b (Hankel) and average the anti-diagonals, since we will seek an approximation of x.b , which will likely not have the proper structure(Hankel), so using diagonal averaging alleviates this problem to some extent. This falls under the topic of singular spectrum analysis. I also fixed the referencing you mentioned.

Comment: I'll take another shot at it if you can explain what you expect the call to `sapply` to do.  Your intent is not clear from the code.

Comment: What I am expecting it to do is on the bottom of page 3. See the link for a PDF. http://bit.ly/ati1ll